# Is there a hash-like function from pointed digraphs where if A and B differ only in the placement of the point, this is clear in the hash?

Tags: graph-theory, cryptography, directed-graphs, hash-function

I want a cryptographically secure hash-like function (it need not output integers, it could be any data type) which takes directed graphs with a single marked point as input, so that if graphs A and B differ only in A's marked point being linked to B's marked point by an edge, it would be possible to recognize this fact easily from the outputs of the function on A and B - but it would not be possible to reverse the function and find out the actual shape of A and B - only that you can change A into B by moving the mark across that edge. Is this possible? How could such a thing be constructed?